# Get Room Price of Overlapping dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table in this structure:

```
id  accom_id    room_type_id    date_from   date_to        price_per_room   
3   1           2               2017-09-01  2017-09-10     70.00    
5   1           2               2017-09-11  2017-09-20     100.00
```

Lets say I want to stay from 2017-09-07 to 2017-09-15. So with DATEDIFF I need to count how many days the price is 70 and how many days the price is 100. At the end I want to show the total.

Can anyone help me build this query? I hope its clear what ask!

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Are we guaranteed that all dates to be queried for will have covering rows and no overlapping rows exist (i.e. there's never a need to supply a default value or for a rule to disambiguate rows)?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.   But with 6 answers already, alas, another satisfied Help Vampire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no overlapping ranges are defined, and assuming that all of the ranges given are meant to be inclusive, we can obtain the data using a CTE and then a simple matter of aggregation:

```
declare @t table (date_from date,date_to date, price_per_room int)
insert into @t (date_from,date_to,price_per_room) values
('20170901','20170910',70.00 ),
('20170911','20170920',100.00)
declare @Start date
declare @End date
select @Start = '20170907',@End = '20170915'

;With IncludedPeriods as (
    select
        CASE WHEN @Start > date_from THEN @Start ELSE date_from END as fromDT,
        CASE WHEN @End < date_to THEN @End ELSE date_to END as ToDT,
        price_per_room
    from
        @t
    where
        date_from <= @End and
        @Start <= date_to
)
select
    SUM(price_per_room * (1 + DATEDIFF(day,fromDT,ToDT)))
from
    IncludedPeriods
```

Note that we're adding one to the `DATEDIFF` result since it counts *transitions*, but I'm assuming that a period *from* '20170911' *to* '20170911' should count as one day and longer periods similarly.

Unlike some of the other answers which attempt to enumerate various "cases" for overlaps, this uses the simple rule - two periods overlap if the first starts before the second ends *and* if the second starts before the first ends - that's the logic applied in the `where` clause inside the CTE. To determine the *extent* of the overlap, we take the later of the two start dates and the earlier of the two end dates - that's what the `CASE` expressions are doing. If we had scalar `MIN` and `MAX` functions that operated on dates I'd prefer to use those but no such functions built into SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can do this:

```
select dateadd(d, number, '20170801')
from master.dbo.spt_values
where type='P' and (number <= datediff(d, '20170801', '20170810'))
```

You **calculate the total days (in the where clause)** and you select the numbers from 0 to total days (`master.dbo.spt_values` is a helpful table in SQL Server). Otherwise you can create a table with ascending numbers from 0 to ?). And then you add to the startdate the number. So you get all days of the booking:

```
2017-08-01 
2017-08-02 
2017-08-03 
2017-08-04 
2017-08-05 
2017-08-06 
2017-08-07 
2017-08-08 
2017-08-09 
2017-08-10
```

Then you can join your given price_table on date_from and date_to and you can calculate your sum.

EDIT: Just to complete it... :-)

```
SELECT SUM(price_per_room)
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    LEFT OUTER JOIN room_prices AS rp ON (date_from <= DATEADD(d, number, my_start_date) AND DATEADD(d, number, my_start_date) <= date_to)
WHERE type='P' AND (number <= DATEDIFF(d, my_start_date, my_end_date))
```

Comment: I think something is missing in the intro of this answer - "In SQL Server (if you have one)..." - I think that's kindof a given on a question tagged [tag:sql-server]. Not clear on what you were going to say so unable to fix myself.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see the tag. I edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a calendar or dates table for this sort of thing.

Without taking the actual step of creating a table, you can use an adhoc tables of dates with a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) like so:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20170907';
declare @thrudate date = '20170915';
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
select total_price = sum(price_per_room)
from dates d
  inner join t
    on d.date >= t.date_from
   and d.date <= t.date_to
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MCF52261

returns:

```
+-------------+
| total_price |
+-------------+
|         780 |
+-------------+
```

---

For a more detailed breakdown of the price and dates, you can swap the above `select` for this one:

```
select 
    fromdate = min(date)
  , thrudate = max(date)
  , days = count(*)
  , price_per_room = avg(price_per_room)
  , total = sum(price_per_room)
from dates d
  inner join t
    on d.date >= t.date_from
   and d.date <= t.date_to
group by grouping sets ((price_per_room),())
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NKZD1468

returns:

```
+------------+------------+------+----------------+-------+
|  fromdate  |  thrudate  | days | price_per_room | total |
+------------+------------+------+----------------+-------+
| 2017-09-07 | 2017-09-10 |    4 | 70             |   280 |
| 2017-09-11 | 2017-09-15 |    5 | 100            |   500 |
| 2017-09-07 | 2017-09-15 |    9 | 86             |   780 |
+------------+------------+------+----------------+-------+
```

---

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-sql/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in sql Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using a Date table(table containing all dates) or a derived table to populate these dates(you can find it online easily) like this:

```
SELECT p.id,p.room_type_id,sum(p.price_per_room)
FROM(
    SELECT t.date,s.price_per_room,s.id,s.room_type_id
    FROM (DATES QUERY \ DATE_TABLE) t
    LEFT JOIN s.yourTable
     ON(t.date between s.date_from and s.date_to)) p
WHERE p.id = YourID and p.room_type_id = YourTypeId
 AND p.date between yourStartDate and yourEndDate
GROUP BY p.id,p.room_type_id
```

That populate a row for each date inside the range of dates for the price, so it will know how much is the price per day, and then just sum the price between your desired dates.

Answer (score -1):

Using `UNION ALL` for all four possible cases may do the job as well

```
SELECT SUM(x.p)
FROM
(
    SELECT (DATEDIFF(DAY, @from, date_to)+1)* price p
    FROM tab
    WHERE date_to BETWEEN @from AND @to AND NOT date_from BETWEEN @from AND @to
      UNION ALL
    SELECT ISNULL(SUM((DATEDIFF(DAY, date_from, date_to)+1)* price), 0) p
    FROM tab
    WHERE date_to BETWEEN @from AND @to AND date_from BETWEEN @from AND @to
      UNION ALL
    SELECT (DATEDIFF(DAY, date_from, @to)+1)* price p
    FROM tab
    WHERE date_from BETWEEN @from AND @to AND NOT date_to BETWEEN @from AND @to
      UNION ALL
    -- in the case that the (@from, @to) interval is completely in one row interval
    SELECT (DATEDIFF(DAY, @from, @to)+1)* price p
    FROM tab
    WHERE date_from <= @from AND date_to >= @to      
)x;
```

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ac014/23)

Comment: What about when `@from` and `@to` are entirely contained within a single row's period (so `date_from` < `@from` and `date_to` > `@to`)? This is why I prefer not to try to define overlaps by trying to analyse separate cases.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever true, I have updated the solution. I admit that your solution is cleaner that was the reason I upvoted it ;)